# twitter4j: getting full name, bio, location, url of user (by username)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How do I get the full name, bio, location, and url of a user by knowing the username in twitter4j?

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
User user = twitter.showUser(username); // this line
if (user.getStatus() != null) {
    System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName() + " - " + user.getDescription());
} else {
    // protected account
    System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
}
```

returns

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are
>   missing.

(tokens and so on  are defined at the beginning. Tweeting, which also requires authentication of course, works fine with that)

Answer (score 2):

You forget to pass the authentification to the TwitterFactory

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("CONSUMER_KEY"); 
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("CONSUMER_SECRET"));
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("TOKEN");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("TOKEN_SECRET");
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
....
```